# Integrating Mailchimp's Mandrill for Transactional Emails in Android

Tags: android, email

Is it possible to integrate Mailchimp's Mandrill transactional email service with Android apps? The docs available at Mandrill.com don't mention anything about platform-specific considerations. Are there any platform-specific issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can integrate Mandrill with web apps, websites, personal email programs, and more.  It's a neutral platform and you can send any legal, non-spam email through the service.  We provide some official API clients, and there are also third-party plugins and integrations.

For any integration, all the logic of when an email should be sent, who it should be sent to, and the content of the email is managed in your own system, database, or code.  Once that information is assembled, you can call the Mandrill API (or use the SMTP integration) and provide the message specifics.  Once the email information is received, Mandrill picks up and will handle delivery and tracking of the email.

Most of the considerations are more generic than the platform you're working with, and will revolve around the type of integration you want to create and what data you're already storing or will be collecting so that you have the information you need to actually create the emails that will be sent.  For example:

- Do you want users of the app to be able to send emails through a Mandrill account?
- Or do you want to send emails to users of the app when certain actions occur, such as downloading or performing an action in the app?

If the first, you might consider whether they'll use their own Mandrill account or if everything will be going through your Mandrill account. If it's all through your account, you might consider imposing certain limitations to prevent people from being able to piggyback on your Mandrill account to send spam.

If you want to email users of the app, consider what information you're collecting about their actions and progress in the app, and when you want emails to be sent. Mandrill doesn't add unsubscribe links to emails, though we do add a List-Unsubscribe header (more details [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21813787-how-do-recipients-unsubscribe-from-emails-sent-through-mandrill)), so you might consider whether you want to allow users to unsubscribe if they don't want the email notifications.

Feel free to add more details about the type of integration you're looking to create with Mandrill and I'll be happy to provide more details if needed. Or you can email us by clicking on the "Submit a Request" button at our help pages: http://help.mandrill.com

Comment: Thanks for the direction. This helps. I will submit a ticket if needed.

Comment: "consider imposing certain limitations to prevent people from being able to piggyback on your Mandrill account to send spam" –can you please elaborate on this? In Android app one can assume that any API keys will be public knowledge. What countermeasures can be taken?

Comment: Ah, got it. You can restrict what API calls the API key can make. Restrict it to, say, "Send-Template", and it's pretty useless to anyone else.